# What is the best way to backup and migrate a windows 2003 IIS 6 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, backup, iis-6, migration

I have a web application running on a windows 2003 IIS 6 server (PHP, MySQL, Zend, cURL, PEAR ... settings about permissions, cache etc. Lots of PHP scripts, on a dedicated machine.

I want to know what is the easiest way to take a snapshot / backup a server configuration. I have all the PHP scripts under version control and backed up locally but its all the settings etc that I want to save also.

I am not very experienced in server admin but have been using Amazon's EC2 to set up Linux machines and we are running some other jobs on a LAMP based image that I have bundled and can start whenever I need. I think this is exactly what I want to be able to do - to take a snapshot of a server and bundle it / back it up.

Also if we change hosting company I want to be able to take this with me and install on the new company and be up and running.

How easy is this, what are the best ways to make this pain free? Any other advice?

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

IIS config is stored in the metabase. You can export everything in the metabase and import it on a new server via export/import in IIS Manager. Just right-click the IIS server whose configuration setting you want to export, select **All Tasks** on the shortcutmenu, and then click **Save Configuration To A File**.